# Is there a way to reconnect two peers after one is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, simple-peer

I'm working with **simple-peer** in React.js to implement a video conference. when I connect two peers after they got disconnected, peers get destroyed but I want to reconnect them on the same connection and I don't want to create a new set of peers and perform the handshake again in order to connect them. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you create new Peer objects on both sides of the connection? Destroying a peer locally will destroy the remote peer it’s connected to.

Also, please post your console logs with debugging enabled.

```
peer._debug = console.log
```